# Analog Stick Wiring

Tags: arduino, potentiometer

I am making an accessible computer interface device with an arduino at the core.  For mouse control, I am using an analog stick, and ordered the Omter OM200B (http://www.omter-tyxn.com/2-axis-potentiometer-joystick-OM200B-M3.html).  It has 3 leads on each on 2 sides (6 total), and I assume that this is power, ground, and data for x and y axis.  Unfortunately, these are not marked, and I am hesitant to guess for fear of frying the analog stick, my arduino, or both.

If I were to hazard a guess, it would be power, data, ground...but that is just a guess.

Is there a particular pattern that these analog sticks need wired?  Is there a standard layout to analog sticks?

Comment: Since your question is specifically about Arduinos, someone may migrate your question to the Arduino stackexchange site.  Your next question should be how to mitigate noise from the ADC process.  Make this a separate independent question over on the Arduino stackexchange site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several models.  The lowest resistance one appears to contain potentiometers that are 5K total resistance.  If we use [V = I x R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) and assume you are using a 5 volt Arduino, we see the total current flowing through the potentiometers is:

```
V = I x R
5 = I x 5,000
I = 5 / 5,000
I = 1mA
```

So the potentiometer needs to get rid of only a small amount of [wattage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watt):

```
W = V x I
W = 5 x 1mA
W = 5mA
```

A [potentiometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer) is normally a [3 terminal device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer#/media/File:Potentiometer_cutaway_drawing.png) with the wiper normally connected to the center terminal.

[image]

So what is normally done is what you stated above.  [Connect 5 volts to one side, the ADC pin to the center and ground to the other side](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/potentiometer).

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is wrong.  These are *analogue* sticks, hence no concept of power, ground and data.  There are two potentiometers for the X and Y axis, respectively.  The common pattern on pots is that the middle pin (marked *w* in the symbol drawing below) is connected to the wiper and two edge pins (marked A & B respectively in the drawing below) are connected to the resistance either end - [image: Potentiometer].

How you use and scan the pots is then a matter of algorithm and circuit design.

The data sheet link provided on the vendor's website is unfortunately not loading, so couldn't advise further.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

These are analog pots with spring centre loading and travel limits that have 4 different models for divider ratio.  These can be applied to any Arduino voltages without power concerns.

The only requirement is that you match the output voltage range as a direct function of R range/ Rtotal for the input range of motion you apply times input voltage across the outer Rtotal leads.

See specs for details on R range and Rtotal, 5K or 10k in 4 models M1,2,3,4

It appears you ordered M3.

> Instruction for choosing model:

- M1: The total resistance value is 5K, but the effect adjustable resistance range is from 1.8K to 2.5K, then from 2.5k to 3.2K.
- M2: The total resistance value is 5K, but the adjustable range is from 0K to 2.5K, then from 2.5K to 5K.
- M3: The total resistance value is 10K, But the adjustable range is from 3.5K to 5k, then from 5K to 6.5K.

> Thus the outer wires can be reversed for polarity and the centre wiper voltage changes +/-15% about 50% of the applied voltage you choose.

i.e. up increasing or decreasing.

This where a DMM comes in handy.